# 持たせる meaning in this sentence

Tags: grammar

There is a character (The hero) who uses a spell and this is the comment another character does on that spell.

> …自らを表す呪文に、自らを律する韻を持たせた英雄。

My translation

> A hero who had a spell which represents him, a rhyme with which he disciplines himself.

Fantraslation

> A hero who used a poem about himself as his spell.

How come it's not 持った but 持たせた?
What's the difference here?

持たせる=To have someone hold something; To allow someone to keep something

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 「[自]{みずか}らを[表]{あらわ}す[呪文]{じゅもん}**に**、自らを[律]{りっ}する[韻]{いん}**を**[持]{も}たせた[英雄]{えいゆう}。」

As is often the case in Japanese phrases and sentences, the key words come in ***kana*** and they are very short.

> 「A + **に** + B + **を** + [持]{も}たせる」

=

> "to let A have B"

「持たせる」 is the ***causative*** form.  You cannot use 「持った」 in this phrase with both に and を.

> "A hero who ***let*** his self-expressing spell ***have*** rhymes to discipline himself."

「自らを律する韻」 is, by no means, a common phrase, so more context (lots of it, perhaps) would be needed for a better translation.

That fan-TL is a joke; you know much better than him/her.